# Automated Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion, cycle

I am trying to make an accordion menu automatically cycle through, and every thing I keep finding is very vague about instructions.  I have found a couple of answers that said I could use the cycle plugin to cycle through, so that's it what I've attempted.  I'm not able to get the cycle function working properly though.  Am I going about it the right way, and if so what have I missed in my code?

I am very new at jQuery, so all of this is a little overwhelming for me.  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
lastBlock = $("#a1");
maxWidth = 380;
minWidth = 50;  

$("#slide ul li a").hover(
  function(){
    $(lastBlock).animate({width: minWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:400 });
$(this).animate({width: maxWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:400});
lastBlock = this;
  }
);
});
 $(function() {
$('#slide').cycle({ 
  fx:     'slideY', 
  easing: 'bounceout', 
  delay:  -4000 
});
});
  </script>

<div id="slide" class="cycle">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="a1">
      <img src="image" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
       <img src="image" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="image" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="image" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about this accordion? http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/... the cycle plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is meant for images. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, in case you didn't know, to alert someone that you have a message meant for them, use `@{name}` - so for me use `@Fudgey` - that person will then get a message flag.

Comment: @Fudgey thanks for the tip on the @{name}  I used this tutorial for the accordion http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion/ so I could use images.  I thought since I was using images that the cycle plugin would be OK.  If there is a better way of getting this done I would definitely be open to trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I wrote a quick solution to hopefully help you get to your solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide" class="cycle">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="a1">
                <img src="image" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="a2">
                <img src="image" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="a3">
                <img src="image" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="a4">
                <img src="image" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var lastBlock = $("#a1");
var maxWidth = 166;
var minWidth = 35;
var counter = 0;
var myInterval = 0;

$("#slide ul li a").mouseenter(

function() {
    $(lastBlock).animate({
        width: minWidth + "px"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 400
    });
    $(this).animate({
        width: maxWidth + "px"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 400
    });
    lastBlock = this;
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    myInterval = setInterval(doSomething, 4000);
});

function doSomething() {
    var i = counter++ % 4 + 1;
    $("#a" + i).trigger("mouseenter");
    $("#a" + i).trigger("mouseleave");
}

myInterval = setInterval(doSomething, 4000);
```

So in this solution, an interval is set to cycle through and trigger the events `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`. Since you might not want the images cycling while your mouse is over an element the interval is cleared upon `mouseenter()` and set up again during `mouseleave()`. A confusing part that could be refactored is the way it cycles through the images using a counter with a modulus operation. Note that I added an ID to each `<a>` with an incremental change to the number at the end.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ck3aZ/

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: I still have a question though... Am I supposed to link the cycle plugin jquery file and the regular jquery file in my header?  I have two in there right now and I don't seem to get the nice finish you got in the example.

Comment: jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery.cycle.min.js                         Is that not correct?

Comment: @Katie My example is not making use of the jQuery cycle plugin, so you would not need to link to that if you use this solution. If you just replace the code inside of your `$(document).ready();` with the provided jQuery and add the extra ID's to the `<a>` tags, it should theoretically work.

Comment: @tinifni I deleted the document ready from the beginning of my script...oops!  It's working great, thank you so much! I would buy you a beer if I could. <br/> I do have one last little question.  If I wanted to specify which image was expanded by default is there a way to do that?  Currently it is loading with all images collapsed. Thanks!

Comment: @Katie Glad it helped you! To get one of them extended by default, try adding `$('#a2').css({'width': maxWidth});` somewhere after the variable declarations (where `#a2` is the ID of the `<a>` housing the image you would like extended). You will also want to update the counter variable to start on the correct `<a>`. A beer would be nice, but I'll settle for having this solution marked as the accepted solution. Happy coding! :D